# Making API calls from browser in a local connection without fixed IP

Tags: reactjs, nginx, ip, webserver

I am running a Nginx web server in a device that has two different network interfaces. I want to serve a React App on port 80 that makes API calls to an API server on a different port of the same device. I have configured Nginx to listen on port 80 and it correctly serves the React app on both interfaces. However, making API calls is trickier.

If I had only one interface with a fixed IP, I would set that IP as the API server address in the React APP and everyhting would be fine. However, when having several interfaces, the React App does not which interface has been used to serve it. As a result, i**t does not know which is the IP of the API server.**

This question is also valid for a device that has only one interface but whose IP changes dyncamically. Nginx serves the web page right regardless of the IP but the React App needs to know the IP address to make API calls to.

I understand that a common solution is to assign a domain to the API server but in my scenario the connection to the device takes place only on a local network.

Solutions I have considered:

1. Having a fixed IP on both interfaces and have nginx serve a different React App to each of the interfaces. The apps would be the same except for the API server address parameter. This is probably an overkill.
2. Requesting the user to enter the IP on the React App when running in the browser. This is not really user friendly.

What I would actually like would be a method for the React App to know the IP through it has been served or a method for Nginx to serve a web with a configuration depending on the device IP. Is there any solution like these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the React app is served in the local network and it does not use a domain, it is requested in the browser using the device IP as href. As a result, the app can get the IP address of the device using the javascript method `window.location.href` and use it as the API server address.